# Game of the nim, minimax

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax

There are 3 piles (1 pile - 7 matches, 2 pile - 5 matches, 3 pile - 3 matches) you can take any number of matches, but only from one pile, the one who takes the last match loses. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim

There is a code that generates all possible moves and stores them in a dictionary ("current position" : "possible positions")

```
def get_moves(initialstate):
    memo = {}
    memo[initialstate] = [move for move in move_list(initialstate)]
    return memo

def move_list(state):
    for i in range(state[0]):
        yield (i, state[1], state[2])
    for i in range(state[1]):
        yield (state[0], i, state[2])
    for i in range(state[2]):
        yield (state[0], state[1], i)

print(get_moves((7,5,3)))
```

how to convert this dictionary into a tree and how to implement minimax?

[I want something like:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax#:%7E:text=function%20%20minimax(node%2C%20depth%2C%20maximizingPlayer)%20is)

```
function  minimax(node, depth, maximizingPlayer) is
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node then
        return the heuristic value of node
    if maximizingPlayer then
        value := −∞
        for each child of node do
            value := max(value, minimax(child, depth − 1, FALSE))
        return value
    else (* minimizing player *)
        value := +∞
        for each child of node do
            value := min(value, minimax(child, depth − 1, TRUE))
        return value
```

I changed the heuristic function, but the computer still chooses the wrong moves, why?
From state [0,1,3] there is a winning state [0,1,0], why does the computer not choose this option?

```
def minimax(position, depth, max_player):
    print(position, evaluate(position))
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluate(position), position
    
    if max_player:
        maxEval = float('-inf')
        best_move = None
        for move in get_moves(position):
            evaluation = minimax(move, depth-1, False)[0]
            maxEval = max(maxEval, evaluation)
            if maxEval == evaluation:
                best_move = move
        
        return maxEval, best_move
    else:
        minEval = float('inf')
        best_move = None
        for move in get_moves(position):
            evaluation = minimax(move, depth-1, True)[0]
            minEval = min(minEval, evaluation)
            if minEval == evaluation:
                best_move = move
        
        return minEval, best_move

def evaluate(position):
    if position == (0,0,0):
        return -100
    if position == (0,0,1) or position == (1,0,0) or position == (0,1,0):
        return 100
    return 1 if (position[0] ^ position[1] ^ position[2]) == 0 else 0

def get_moves(initialstate):
    memo = [move for move in move_list(initialstate)]
    return memo

def move_list(state):
    for i in range(state[0]):
        yield (i, state[1], state[2])
    for i in range(state[1]):
        yield (state[0], i, state[2])
    for i in range(state[2]):
        yield (state[0], state[1], i)
        
print(list(minimax((0,1,3),12,True)[1]))
```

Comment: Why do you need a minimax structure? The Nim game does not feature any scoring, so there is only a win and a loss. There are winning positions and losing positions, and the winning strategy does not involve any minimax optimisation, rather it involves computing the xor of the piles and subtracting such a number of matches from the one of the heaps so that the xor becomes zero. [Here's the theory on wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim#Mathematical_theory)

Comment: So what is your idea for a heuristic function? What should it look at? What is "good" about a state, and what is "bad"?

Comment: So your heuristic function would only give either 0 or 1 as return value? Did you try implementing that?

Comment: Better edit your question so you can present that code in a readable way.

Comment: Can you add the code to make it runnable? So, including the `evaluate` function and the driver code that calls this? What does "doesn't work" mean concretely?

Comment: I still don't understand why this should be minimax. The XOR heuristic (if applied correctly) gives a *definite* evaluation of the state. There is no gain in looking deeper -- that will not change that evaluation. I give up.

Comment: I reverted your last edit, as the information that this is about the Nim game (the example, the link to Wikipedia, ...) is relevant to understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be no different from any other implementation of minimax, e.g. for tic tac toe. For each turn you go through all possible moves (draw a stick from any of the piles) and see what the corresponding game state is (win/loss/draw). A draw in this case would be that there still are sticks left in all piles, a win is that opponent draws last stick in a pile, and a loss is that you draw the last stick in a pile.

You don't need to store it in a dict. You can have a general "board" which holds the current game state (sticks in each pile). Then in each minimax iteration you get all possible moves from the current board state (e.g. get_possible_moves(board)).

Comment: You don't store the moves. You calculate them each iteration of minimax before you go through the board.

Comment: In tic tac toe example you have a boardstate (9 squares with either X or O or empty). Then depending on the boardstate the player has some moves (place its marker on an empty square). This leads to a new board state with new possible moves. In your case you have a boardstate (3 piles with different amount of sticks). Then in each boardstate you calculate the possible moves (take a stick from one of the piles) and loop through them all which each will give a different boardstate that you again calculate the possible moves for and so on.

Comment: Honestly this is a bit of a complicated algorithm for this sort of game, I would use something completely different altogether, but it seemed like you needed to use minimax.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- The `minimax` function will return `None` as value when there are no possible moves (i.e. when the state is `(0,0,0)`). Instead the `evaluate` function should be ran in that case, just like when `depth == 0`.
- As you use the concept of a maximizing and minimizing player, the base case is not correct: `return -100` would indicate that this is a win for the minimizing player, while in really depends who did the last move. The same goes for the next `return 100`.

  For this reason I would suggest to *not* work with the concept of maximizing/minimizing players, but consider both players as maximizing, and toggle the sign of the value that is returned.
- In the XOR part, I would return -1 instead of 0, so that it really is the opposite value of 1.
- As this flavour of the Nim game is the "misère" version (see Wikipedia), the base case should include any case where the largest pile has a size of 1. So, not only `(1,0,0)`, but also `(1, 1, 1)` and `(1, 0, 1)` ... etc.

Here is a correction:

```
def minimax(position, depth):
    val = evaluate(position)
    # Use heuristic when depth is reached OR when no more moves possible
    if depth == 0 or val == -100:  
        return -val, None  # No move associated with this value
    
    maxEval = -1000
    best_move = None
    for move in get_moves(position):
        # Negate returned value to make it relevant for current player
        evaluation = -minimax(move, depth-1)[0]
        maxEval = max(maxEval, evaluation)
        if maxEval == evaluation:
            best_move = move
    return maxEval, best_move

def evaluate(position):
    # Evaluate the board in the view of 
    #     the player that last moved
    if max(position) <= 1:  # Largest pile size is at most 1?
        # Must leave odd number of non-empty piles to win
        return 100 if sum(position) % 2 else -100
    # Must leave a XOR sum of zero. Use 1 or -1.
    return 1 if (position[0] ^ position[1] ^ position[2]) == 0 else -1
```

Finally, as this "heuristic" is not really a heuristic, but a perfect evaluation of the state, I don't see the use of minimax here, as the best move will be found with a depth of 1. Passing a higher value of `depth` will not lead to better moves. If you want that a player will play a most-promising move when in a **loosing** position, you'll need to add a *real* heuristic, which expresses what exactly that "most-promising" means; like:

- *"choose the move for which the other player has the least possibilities to play a winning move"*, or
- *"choose the move which delays the loss for as long as possible"*, or
- *"choose a move which maximizes the number of piles that are non-empty"* (reasoning that the game is easier for a human to play correctly when it has fewer non-empty piles)

Comment: To you first comment. [I cannot reproduce that](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma718873115459839) To your second comment: `minimax` is initially called when the computer makes a move, but during minimax, the moves alternate, so also moves are played (as part of that minimax) which are for the computer's opponent. And also then `evaluate` can be called.

Comment: If you are going to use random, then the whole idea of minimax is even more useless. I am not sure you understand what I have been saying about this. But this was not in your question, so I suppose this random thing should be a subject of a new question if you really cannot solve that. A question should be focusing on one particular issue only.